# Get the css properties using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I use

```
$('#mybutton').css('padding-top')
```

its work perfectly in `firefox` but its not work in `chrome`. Help me to write generalized way to get css property values in all the browsers

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is working fine even chrome also. I have tested it. And if you want width then you can use .width()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to read css property you can follow the same way as you stated in Question i.e.

```
$('#mybutton').css('padding-top');
```

To read width or height, jQuery provided functions like `.width()` or `.height()`.
**NOTE** - don't forget to put `$` at the start of statement

```
$('#mybutton').width();
```

**EDIT** as suggested by @ RokoC.Buljan, put your jquery script inside `document.ready` or `$(function(){..});` to ensure that DOM is ready, see below examples

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mybutton').width();
    $('#mybutton').css('padding-top'); 
});
```

OR

```
$(function(){
    $('#mybutton').width();
   $('#mybutton').css('padding-top');
});
```

**[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/r2eqeL2a/7/)**

Comment: Thank you but in this same way can i take padding properties.

Comment: General way of reading css property is same as you posted i.e. `$('#mybutton').css('padding-top');`. Can you please share jsfiddle link with your problem statement? I shall look into it.

Comment: Try to put `$('#mybutton').css('padding-top');` in `$(function(){});` as suggested in answer. working link http://jsfiddle.net/r2eqeL2a/7/

Comment: This is the link of jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VenkatesanNarayanan/bcwc49de/5/ thanks in advance

Comment: it is showing `undefined` on both chrome and firefox.

Comment: You have to give some value for `padding-top` then it will give you an alert

Comment: After giving padding also its not comming http://jsfiddle.net/VenkatesanNarayanan/bcwc49de/12/

Comment: you are trying to find `#btn` inside `$controls`, but here `$controls` itself is `div` with `id=btn`, use this link http://jsfiddle.net/bcwc49de/13/

Comment: Thank you it works. if i want to take that button css property how i can take for eg:-http://jsfiddle.net/VenkatesanNarayanan/bcwc49de/14/

Comment: Could you please upvote and accept this answer if you are satisfied with the solution

Comment: sorry I don't have sufficient reputation to vote up this answer.But i really satisfied with your answers thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure DOM is ready before targeting your elements:

```
$(function(){ // DOM is now ready

   var val = $('#myButton').css('desired-property');
   console.log( val );

});
```

Answer (score -1):

It is working fine even in chrome also. I have tested it. Please check your selector may be you are making mistake there.